# Type mismatch after cabal update?

Tags: haskell, cabal

Program has the following import:

```
import Pipes.Network.TCP
import Pipes
import Pipes.Core
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
```

Compilation fails like so:

```
Couldn't match expected type `bytestring-0.9.2.1:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString'
            with actual type `C.ByteString'
Expected type: Proxy
                 Int
                 bytestring-0.9.2.1:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString
                 ()
                 b0
                 m0
                 ()
  Actual type: Proxy Int C.ByteString () C.ByteString IO ()
```

I can be more specific about the code, but it looks like this is not related to code - rather some cabal whim. Perhaps, `Pipes` that I import are considered to use a different `ByteString` than the one imported with qualified name.

The program used to compile some time ago (I have its working executable), but now it stopped, and I suspect there could have been some cabal update or package installation. How to debug and fix this?

Comment: Yeah, you have two different versions of `bytestring` installed, and two packages you have installed each depends on a different version. This is why cabal warns you that "reinstalls are always dangerous". There is light at the end of the tunnel (["no-reinstall cabal"](http://blog.ezyang.com/2015/08/help-us-beta-test-no-reinstall-cabal/)), but you may want to nuke your sandbox or `.ghc` and try again.

Comment: Yes, you should remove the `bytestring` that did not come with your GHC and anything that depends on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your program is built with cabal, you should re-configure it. This may highlight other problems, such as dependencies which would require re-installing or breaking other parts of the dependency tree. The "old way" to solve this is to progressively `cabal install` more and more things until the dependency solver agrees it's possible, e.g.

```
$ cabal install .
# complains that reinstalls might break lens
$ cabal install . lens
# complains that reinstalls might break bytestring
$ cabal install . lens bytestring
# complains that reinstalls might break X
$ cabal install . lens bytestring X
```

...etc. The "new way" is to use [no-reinstall cabal](http://blog.ezyang.com/2015/08/help-us-beta-test-no-reinstall-cabal/). You will still need to reconfigure before you build, and may need to install some dependencies again to transition properly.